# Do works in background indefinitely

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I need to have a background thread that works indefinitely. I've wrote this code to define an IntentService:

```
public class RecordInternetUsageService extends IntentService {

public RecordInternetUsageService() {
    super("test");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            wait(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I have two questions, Is it a suitable class to do works indefinitely in background? 
Why when I want to sleep this thread using by wait() method, Throws me an exception that mentioned below?
"sending message to a Handler on a dead thread".

 And how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do long processing task even when your application is closed i.e. in background one has to use Service... but you can do long processing work on that Main thread of Service or else you get ANR(android not responding). So you have to make a background thread and submit all the task on that background thread(That is done by **Handle** class) and handle all submitting and responding stuff... to wrap up this design pattern **IntenServcie** class is offered.

IntentService class automatically invokes the thread when a job is submitted and when the job is completed it kills the sevrice and frees up the memory. IntentSerive Exits as soon as it is done with its job.

The problem here is that you are creating a Toast inside a thread that is managed by the IntentService. The system will use the Handler associated with this thread to show and hide the Toast.

First the Toast will be shown correctly, but when the system tries to hide it, after the onHandleIntent method has finished, the error "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" will be thrown because the thread in wich the Toast was created is no longer valid,.